# p:poll stopped but still fires network call

Tags: jsf, primefaces, backing-beans

I have to stop and start a `p:poll` in JSF using some conditions... I am able to do that by putting the poll in a panelgrid and making the panelGrid rendered... I thought its working since the    pollOperationStatus is not called after I made the panelGrid rendered false... When I show it , it restarts as well.. 
But there is a  network call still firing ; which messes up many things ;How to deal it?

```
 <h:form>
    My main form
    </h:form>

        <h:form id="mypollform">

            <p:outputLabel id="currentTime" value="#{myBean.counter}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{myBean.startPoll}" id="counter11" />

            <p:panelGrid rendered="#{myBean.startPoll}">
                <p:poll interval="8" widgetVar="poller" autoStart="true"
                    listener="#{myBean.pollOperationStatus}"
                    update=":#{p:component('newServerID')},:#{p:component('mypollform')}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: So you actually mean that you can start the poll, stop the poll but it then keeps on doing network calls? And if you start it again it is doing duplicate calls?

Comment: i didnt start again..but after stopping , there are network calls

Comment: Then your original description was not fully correct. Effectively the stopping did not work correctly... The answer by @Selaron is your solution

Comment: Stopping works!.. its not calling any more of the listener... it just fires a network request...

Comment: **the answer by @Selaron is you solution** focus on that please and accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 2):

[Primefaces 7 Documentation says](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/poll):

> Poll can be started and stopped using client side api; Or bind a
>   boolean variable to the `stop` attribute and set it to false at any
>   arbitrary time.

In your case this would be in `javaScript`:

`PF('poller').stop();` or `PF('poller').start();`

Or bind a `boolean` bean property the the `stop` attribute of the `p:poll`:

```
<p:poll stop="#{myBean.stopPoller}" interval="8" widgetVar="poller" autoStart="true"
                    listener="#{myBean.pollOperationStatus}"
                    update=":#{p:component('newServerID')} :#{p:component('mypollform')}" />
```

<strike>Also beware that component IDs in `update` attribute [are separated by space, not comma.](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/ajax/rendering)</strike>

Comment: From the documentation you refer to: _"Multiple components to update can be specified with providing a list of ids separated by a comma, whitespace or even both."_ PrimeFaces ajax differs here from basic JSF, but it is better to adhere to the basic JSF. (off-topic: almost 3000 rep... close votes coming close)

Comment: Damn have so overseen that... thanks. (off-topic: And yes I'm working on it ^^)